# Failed to generate posterior samples in OpenBUGS

Tags: simulation, bayesian, winbugs, openbugs

I am trying to calculate the Bayesian predictive probability P(P(Diff>0)>0.95), for two sample means. I assume the following

```
(1) Standard deviation = 1.44 for both groups
(2) mean 1 = 2.06, mean 2 = 1.34 so we expect to show a mean difference of 0.72
(3) In group 1, n = 80; In group 2, n = 40
(4) we try to borrow information for n = 30 from both group, so those 30 were treated as prior information, and data should be collected for n = 50 from group 1, and n = 10 from group 2.
```

My OpenBUGS code are

```
model{
# likelihoods 
for (i in 1:n){
    x[i]  ~ dnorm(mua,taua)
    y[i]  ~ dnorm(mup,taup)
    diff[i] <- x[i] - y[i]
    difffl[i] <- step(diff[i])
  }
  # normal priors
  mua ~ dnorm(mu1, inv.sigma)
  mup ~ dnorm(mu2, inv.sigma)
  inv.sigma <- n3/sigma.squared
  taua <- n1/sigma.squared
  taup <- n2/sigma.squared
  # calculate the probability P(diff > delta)
  # delta will be 0 here; # eta will be 0.95 here
  # calculate the predictive probability P(P(diff >delta)>0.95)
  sdx <- sd(x[])
  sdy <- sd(y[])
  mdiff <- mean(diff[])
  mdifffl <- mean(difffl[])
  powerfl <- step(mdifffl - 0.95)
}
list(mu1 = 2.06, mu2 = 1.34, n = 1000, n1 = 50, n2 = 10, n3 = 30, 
sigma.squared = 2.0736)
```

And my results are

```
mean    sd  MC_error    val2.5pc    median  val97.5pc   start   sample
mdiff   0.7152  0.3724  0.003383    -0.01549    0.7143  1.46    1   10000
mdifffl 0.8749  0.1376  0.001318    0.489   0.924   0.999   1   10000
powerfl 0.3932  0.4885  0.005197    0.0 0.0 1.0 1   10000
sdx     0.2036  0.004437    4.722E-5    0.195   0.2036  0.2124  1   10000
sdy     0.4552  0.01011 1.079E-4    0.4357  0.4551  0.4752  1   10000
```

The results don't look correct, as the standard deviation of mean in group 1 (sdx) should be 1.44/sqrt(80) = 0.161. current value 0.2036 in fact is 1.44/sqrt(50). The power I obtained is also too small (powerfl = 0.3932, which should be around 93%). Seems the code ddin't generate samples from posterior distributions.

It will be great if someone can take a look at my code and find the mistake inside. Much appreciated!

best,